# Xamarin forms- dynamically created webview not firing events

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I am trying to automate one website data extraction by dynamically creating a `WebView` and loading the source url. I want the `Page` and `WebView` not to be displayed to the user. Unfortunately the events don't seem to work. Any help appreciated.

Creating a `ContentPage` and adding XAML in design time works fine.

**Edit 1:**
Thanks Paul for helping me with the detailed event model. 
Unfortunately my requirement is NOT to display the page and the webview to the user. Looks like the webview events doesn't fire if it is not added to the visual tree :-(.

May be I should explain bit more on what I am trying to achieve. What is the best way to automate a website crawling from a 'xamarin forms'/'xamarin android' platform app/service?(I have added service here since at one point I want to automate this in background) I started exploring with the webview since it uses the native browser and has pretty good JavaScript support and even allows dynamic javascript injection. Is there any alternatives like a headless browser which is capable of the same including javascript injection? I still prefer the webview because of its flexibility and I hope we can make it working somehow.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```cs
ContentPage cp = new ContentPage();
cp.Title = "My Page";
StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();
var webView = new WebView();

sl.Children.Add(webView);
cp.Content = sl;

webView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
webView.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;

webView.Source = "https://www.google.com/";//just a sample i tried multiple urls including http

private async void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //event not firing!
}

private async void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    //event not firing!
}
```

Comment: Hi , Which is the version of Xamrin Forms used in project ?

Comment: My xamarin forms version is 4.2.0.709249

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what exactly you are going to do, but if you want your webview to be invisible you can use the **isVisible** property.

you could dynamically create webview in one displaying page.

for example ,this is a displaying page:

```
 public partial class HyWeb : ContentPage
{
    public HyWeb()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.WidthRequest = 500;
        webView.HeightRequest = 500;
        webView.IsVisible = false;
        webView.Source = "https://www.google.com";
        webView.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;
        webView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
        Stl.Children.Add(webView);
    }
    private void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("navigated");
    }

    private void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("navigating");
    }

}
```

page xaml ：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App18"
         x:Class="App18.HyWeb">
    <ContentPage.Content>
       <StackLayout x:Name="Stl">
         <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
       </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

when i click the button,it will dynamically create webview,but the webview will not be displayed to the user

Comment: Thanks for helping. In fact I do NOT want neither the page nor the webview to be visible to the user.

Comment: @user698006 yes，i know，so you could do like above in a displaying page ，not to open a new page

Comment: I have seen that a hidden webview inside a visible page worksfine. I was trying to make it working behind the scenes and reusable for a background service/scheduler as well. Pls see my edits to the original question above

Comment: i think you don't need to use a background service/scheduler if you just want to get the html data of thew webview page,you just need create a customrenderer of webview,and injection Js to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

While what Leo Zhu wrote is correct - from an practical point of view - let me get into the details a bit.

The way you are creating the `WebView` you don't add it to the visual tree of your app, because a page is created but never displayed.

I've created a small example you can find in the Annex, in which I created a page that contains a button that adds a `WebView` to that page. Anyway, this `WebView` is not created when the button is clicked, but in the constructor of my page. The `Navigated` event calls a method that logs when the event was raised.

Furthermore I created a custom renderer to log when the renderer for the `WebView` is instantiated and when the native control is created.

My debug messages occurred in the following order

```
[0:] WebView created
[0:] Button clicked
[0:] Creating renderer
[0:] Creating native control
[0:] WebView navigated
```

This way, you can see that - while the Xamarin.Forms view is created within the constructor - the native renderer (that is responsible for creating the native view, which in turn is responsible for loading the website) is instantiated *after* the button was clicked (i.e. after the view has been added to the visual tree of the app). Afterwards the renderer creates the native control that loads the website. Finally, after the website is loaded, the `Navigated` event is raised. It's basically the same if I add the `WebView` to a page and display this page after the button is pressed.

### Annex (Code)

XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SOTest20191112.MainPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Button Text="Create WebView" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```cs
namespace SOTest20191112
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    using Xamarin.Forms;

    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private WebView _webView;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._webView = new WebView
                              {
                                  Source = new UrlWebViewSource()
                                               {
                                                   Url = "http://www.google.de"
                                               }
                              };
            _webView.Navigated += WebViewOnNavigated;
            Debug.WriteLine("WebView created");
        }

        private void WebViewOnNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WebView navigated");
        }

        private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button clicked");

            if (!this.StackLayout.Children.Contains(this._webView))
            {
                this.StackLayout.Children.Add(this._webView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom renderer

```cs
using SOTest20191112.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(WebViewRenderer))]

namespace SOTest20191112.Droid
{
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Webkit;

    class WebViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRenderer
    {
        public WebViewRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Creating renderer");
        }

        protected override WebView CreateNativeControl()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Creating native control");
            return base.CreateNativeControl();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, please see my edits to the original question